# Database: 70+ Columns or Multiple Tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Building a database system for my local Medical Association.
What we have is a list with something like 70+ fields of information for each member of the association. Stuff like name, surname, home address, office address, phone numbers, specialty +++ many small details.

At the moment i've built one table with all the information related to the docs + other tables for related stuff like subscription payments, requests, penalties etc.

I'm quite new to database design, and while it works, I find my design ugly. It is logical, as all information in each row is unique and belongs to just one person, but i'm sure there would be a better way to do it.

How would you go for it? Should I do multiple 1:1 tables, 1 for each subject (basic info, contact info, education, etc) or just keep it as it is? One table with 70+ columns.

Comment: Use an attribute-value table for miscellaneous data, rather than dedicated columns.

Comment: Consider whether sparse columns, i.e. with many null values, should be in separate tables.

Comment: Consider that while a single table with many columns is preferable for reporting, for a transactional system, performance and concurrency is increased by collating related entities together in dedicated tables.

Comment: That depends entirely on what you're storing in each column. Find a tutorial or buy a book and read about database normalization so you'll know what the best option would be.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry about 70 columns in a table. This is not a problem for MySQL.

MySQL can support many more columns. InnoDB's hard limit on the number of columns in a table is 1000.
Read this blog about [Understanding the Maximum Number of Columns in a MySQL Table](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/04/08/understanding-the-maximum-number-of-columns-in-a-mysql-table/) for details.

It's more convenient to put all the attributes into a table that belong with that table. It will take more coding work to support separating columns into multiple tables if you feel you need to do that.

If some of the columns are not applicable, use NULL. NULL takes almost no storage in MySQL, so you won't be "wasting" any space by having a lot of columns most of which are NULL.

The only downside is that you may find yourself adding more columns as time goes on, and that could be inconvenient if the table grows large and access to the table is blocked while you are altering it. In that case, learn to use [pt-online-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-online-schema-change.html), a free tool that allows you to alter tables while continuing to use them.

Answer (score 0):

1:1 is rarely wise.  But it may be advisable if you have "too many" columns, especially if they are "too bulky".

Do use suitable datatypes for the columns -- ints, dates, etc.

Do use suitable `VARCHAR` sizes, not blindly `VARCHAR(255)` or `TEXT`.  (This will help later in certain subtle limits and in performance.)

Study the data.  If, for example, only half the persons have a "subscription", then the 5 columns relating to a subscription can (should) be moved to a separate table.  Probably the subscription table would have a `person_id` for linking to the main table.  This is potentially 1:many (one person to many subscriptions) if that is relevant.

By splitting off some columns, you avoid lots of NULLs.  Nulls are not harmful; it just seems sloppy if there are lots of nulls.

If you are talking about only a few hundred rows, then you are unlikely to encounter significant performance issues regardless of how you structure the tables.

"phone numbers" used to come in "home" and "work".  Now there is "fax", "cell", "emergency contact", and even multiple numbers of any category.  That is very likely a 1-person-to-many-numbers.

Selectively "normalize" the data.  You said "local".  It may be worth "normalizing" (city, state, zip) into a separate table.  Or it may not be worth the effort.  I argue that you should no normalize phone numbers.

Do not have an "array" of things splayed across columns.  Definitely use a separate table when such occurs.

Do think about 1:1, 1:many, and many:many when building "entity" tables and their "relationships".

If you have a million rows, these tips become more important and need to be pondered carefully.

Comment: It's around 600 rows at the moment. I don't expect adding more than 20-30 extra rows per year.

While most information is "usefull" like contact details, ID numbers etc, there's way to much stuff that's used as an archive. University Diplomas, diploma number, year of graduation, then the same for masters degree and phd for example. All these are unique values to each doctor, that's why i'm using just one table atm.

Comment: In designing table structures, I like to write the `SELECTs/UPDATEs/etc` as an exercise to see if the schema is "good".